# Are linear referencing services supported in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, linear-referencing

Does ArcGIS Online support services which have linear referencing enabled?

I know Linear Referencing is supported in ArcGIS Server, but cannot find any support for ArcGIS Online.

Answer (score 0):

If ArcGIS Server is out of scope then I think your best option is to follow and vote for the ArcGIS Idea to [Add Linear Referencing Support to ArcGIS Online](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-ideas/add-linear-referencing-support-to-arcgis-online/idi-p/941058):

> ArcGIS Online (AGO) does not support linear referencing/dynamic
> segmentation of events in tables.  Linear referencing is an essential
> workflow in transportation organizations which store much of their
> data in tables that require dynamic segmentation to visualize or
> spatially analyze.  The National Hydrography Dataset (NHD) also relies
> on liner referencing to place water supply and water quality features
> on the NHD network.
>
> Without linear referencing support in AGO, web-based users have no
> access to use the power of GIS analysis on much of their enterprise
> tabular data.  Organizations have huge investments in legacy data and
> data collected and stored in event tables that are not available to
> AGO users, only Desktop users.
>
> This could be implemented by allowing an organization to add a Roads
> and Highways LRS Service to their organization, like Address Locators
> are handled, now.  User could access the service by adding data in a
> spreadsheet or CSV format (like geocoding is done).

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo, I had seen that idea. It was from 2016 and I had hoped that they had implemented it by now, but it appears they haven't.

Comment: @Fezter I'm likely to be looking for this functionality soon so if I come across anything I'll be sure to revise my answer.